# Is it possible using azure application insights availability test to have audio alerts along with an email?

Tags: azure

So I have set up availability tests for all of our sites, I am wondering if it possible to have audio alerts when one of these site goes down. I don't know whether this is possible, if not can I have some suggestions on what else i could do to have the audio alerts.

Comment: Some mail clients let you play a sound when a mail arrives. That could be an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alerts in Azure can notify via email or webhook. You can hook them up to something which plays audio/does phone call/etc.

Comment: For example, a Flow or Logic App that sends a text message via Twilio from a webhook